# What to do with [flow] tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

I think there's some opportunity for improvement in the [flow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flow), but I'm not sure what improvements should be made.

It looks like many of the questions are related to flow-control, but there's also network flow and some other flows.

The tag description is just plain confusing to me. The quote simply does not work as a wiki excerpt.

What should be done with the flow tag?

Comment: +1, the current tag wiki is about a subject that is no longer on-topic on SO. That wrongly suggests that questions about being "in the flow" are on-topic, so something should be done.

Comment: -1, no clever title using the tag's name :)

Comment: Let it [flow], let it [flow]...

Answer (score 2):

That tag needs to be disambiguated.

Its current tag wiki is about "being in the flow", which is no longer a subject on Stack Overflow. This gives a wrong signal: that questions about "being in the flow" are on-topic on SO, which is not the case. If nothing else, the tag wiki should be changed.

If "being in the flow" is a subject to ask questions about, it should be on [Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com) or maybe [The Workplace](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/). On Programmers, the tag exists but doesn't have a tag wiki; it needs to be disambiguated there as well, because there too it is used for different things.

For Stack Overflow, I suggest to split it:

1. 'flow' as in 'the zone' is no longer appropriate for Stack Overflow. Close these questions, or migrate them if they're not too old.
2. Flowchart questions should be retagged to [flowchart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flowchart).
3. Questions about network-flow should be retagged to [network-flow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/network-flow).
4. Questions about TYPO3-Flow should be retagged to [typo3-flow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/typo3-flow).

There may be a few more cases. I haven't found a tag for "code flow", and it may not always be appropriate to tag questions about code flow with "flowchart". A flowchart is the concrete representation of a code flow, which is subtly different from a code flow itself. We may have to create a "code flow" tag.

Another case is the "flow" from an end user's point of view. A few of the questions tagged with "flow" are about that. These questions don't always belong on [User Experience](https://ux.stackexchange.com/), the ones I've looked at were about how to *implement* a specific end user experience, not about designing one. However, I don't think we need a special tag for that, it would be a bit of a meta-tag.

As for [flow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flow) itself, with its current tag wiki it is not appropriate for Stack Overflow. If we are to keep it, I think we should have a "code flow" tag, and make "flow" a tag synonym of "code flow".

Comment: The term for "code flow" is [tag:control-flow].

Comment: And for Facebook Flow it should be [tag:flowtype], according to [Which tag should I use for Facebook Flow questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/359074)

Answer (score 1):

The tag itself needs to be burninated due to being ambiguous and replaced by more specific tags wherever it's used. [@S.L.Barth elaborated on the details fine](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271354/what-to-do-with-flow-tag/271355#271355).

Answer (score -1):

Can we use the flow tag to be use for topics related to Microsoft Flow? Seems everyone who has been using it lately has been posting questions related to it.

Comment: I've scanned the last 30 questions asked and I'm not seeing that much Microsoft Flow questions. Also there exists [tag:microsoft-flow] so if anything the questions asked in the [tag:flow] that are about the microsoft product should be retagged.

Comment: Ah, thanks, I tried searching for it as I was sure it must have existed, but wasn't clever enough to try microsoft-hyphen-flow

Comment: We have a hyphen loaded history, so never rule them out ...