# Which tag should I use for Facebook Flow questions?

Tags: discussion, tags

I'm going to ask a [question](//stackoverflow.com/q/47183924/4928642) about [flow](https://flow.org/en/) - static type checking for javascript.

According to [flow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flow) description

> This is a meta tag and should not be used.  See the wiki for more information.
>
> See this meta question for more information
>
> http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/277169/1228

I should use the other tag. The answer to the specified question says

> > Create a [facebook-flow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/facebook-flow) tag
>
> Sure. But not before it's needed. Oh wait, it [already exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/facebook-flow).

But when I'm looking at that page I see

> 0 questions tagged [facebook-flow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/facebook-flow)

**So what tag shoud I use??**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Flow website tells you which tag to use. See the Stack Overflow icon at the top right of the page: [flowtype](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flowtype)

Comment: Thank you! This name is enugh unexpected for me.